# EXTJS how to let json post with square bracket even 1 object only

Tags: json, extjs

```
var RouteSeqStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'RouteSeqModel',
        storeId: 'RouteSeqStore',
        autoLoad: false,
        sorters: [{
                    property: 'Route_Seq',
                    direction: 'ASC'
                }],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'route/get-routeseq.php',
            api: {
                    destroy: 'route/delete-routeseq.php',
                    create: 'route/insert-routeseq.php',
                    //read: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=read',
                    update: 'route/update-routeseq.php',

                },
            actionMethods: 'POST',
            baseParams: {
                    _id : 0,
                },  
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty: '_id'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                id: '_id'

             }
        }
    });
```

this is my EXTJS post json code, when posting 1 object, extjs wont have square bracket

```
{"_id":11,"Route_Seq":1,"Location_Name":"B.STATION","Route_LocationID":"1","Route_ID":"2","id":null}
```

when multi array json result will having the `[ ]` bracket, how to let JSON post with square bracket even 1 object only

what i expect the result is :

```
[{"_id":11,"Route_Seq":1,"Location_Name":"B.STATION","Route_LocationID":"1","Route_ID":"2","id":null}]
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: just set the **`allowSingle`** config on your writer to be "false". This will force the writer to send model instances as an array ALWAYS, regardless of the number being persisted in any given request. Be sure to **[check out the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.writer.Json-cfg-allowSingle)** for this.